# What are the possible answers for this question "Why didn't you join as an employee?"

Tags: job-offer, meetings, contracting

I am working for a big insurance company as Contractor joined 6 months ago.
I have a meeting with one of our Sr Directors to get to know each other. Our team is small-medium sized, about 40 members. Half of them members are contractors from different companies. Managers randomly take contractors as Full-time, if they are eligible. There is no pattern, when and on what basis they take. However, they are the ones that the initiation comes from.

One of the questions I might get asked is, 
"Why didn't you join as an employee?" or 
"Why don't you join as an employee?"

I am eligible to be hired as a full-time employee. But as I mentioned, manager(s) have to initiate the request. We can't ask them to hire us as full time.

Being this the case, what are the possible answers for the above questions? (PS: My meeting is with Sr Director, Not my manager(s)).

Sr. Director doesn't know much about me or my eligibility and how long I have been a contractor, etc. He just knows that I am part of his team and working as a contractor.

Comment: Why would you answer with anything but the truth?

Comment: Yes, Truth. But there are ways to present the truth. In my situation, I could say "I am ready to join as an employee." and leave it or "I have never been asked to join a full time", etc.. But these can be framed in a professional manner and there are better answers to these questions. Thats what I wanted to know.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to clarify that in your question. There are _many_ situations where people don't want to be full time employees, and the reasons behind them (and what to answer when prompted) would make it difficult for there to be a single clear answer to the question.

Comment: Do you want to work full time? Some people like contract as they can do something different every 6 months. You may be open to working full time or not. Maybe you're open to it for the right position and benefits. All things you can discuss with this person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were asked that, I would consider that he is trying to feel you out about whether you would be interested in joining as an employee as they certainly would not ask this question if they had no intent to offer you that status.

Therefore the best answer is one that let's them know you would be interested in it, but that the action is up to them to take.  Something like:

"I haven't been offered the opportunity yet, but I certainly would consider it if an offer was made." Be careful not to commit to accepting any offer they made or you might get low-balled on the salary.

Of course if you didn't want to be given an offer, then a smile and "I'm happy where I am." would suffice.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me unlikely you'll be asked that.  Surely a higher up would be aware that your manager has to initiate the process, and possibly would also be aware of some outside circumstances not personally related to you that might have led to the process not being initiated.  It's also the kind of question that is putting you needlessly on the spot, when he could consult your manager about it.

If you were asked that however, and assuming you would like to be hired full time, I would probably just respond with, "I haven't been offered that opportunity," and tell him that you don't know the particulars as to why.  If you don't want to be hired full time, you could alternatively respond with whatever circumstances make you not want to be hired full time.

But also if you would like to be hired as full-time, I would recommend actually talking to your boss about the opportunity to be hired full-time.  Sometimes it takes your actually pushing for it, for things like that to gain momentum.

Comment: Sounds to me like maybe this senior director is second-guessing the middle-management, and wants to hear from the *employees* to help dig into what's up with "managers randomly take contractors as Full-time, if they are eligible. There is no pattern". Of course if the questioner's opinion is typical, asking the contractors won't help find any obscure pattern there might be, since they know nothing. And maybe I'm just a cynic for thinking directors and managers aren't in perfect unison on this one ;-)